# Is ENTER_FRAME dispatched at the end of vertical blanking signal or at the start of window?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d, vsync, enterframeevent

Is ENTER_FRAME dispatched at the end of vertical blanking signal (vblank or vsync) -the actual beginning of the frame on the screen, OR at the beginning of the flash window (if the stage3D app is in window mode), OR in an imprecise timing (depending on the ...internal mood of Flash)?

(I'm using pure AS3 and Stage3D with 3D GPU rendering -no 2D display objects, Flash timeline, movieclips etc).

EDIT: See relative question:[Can the ENTER_FRAME be missed or received delayed by the listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988765/can-the-enter-frame-event-be-missed-or-received-delayed-by-the-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit old but still mostly true: http://www.craftymind.com/2008/04/18/updated-elastic-racetrack-for-flash-9-and-avm2/

So shortly said - ENTER_FRAME is dispatched at the beginning of the frame, then code is executed, and after all that, the render begins (I don't know what you exactly mean by vblank, vsync or 'beginning of the frame on the screen')..

Comment: Interesting article on that link, thanks. vblank is the signal that syncs each monitor screen refresh cycle to the PC desktop (or other device) frame rate. It starts at the end of the previous screen refresh as a negative pulse. (In old CRT monitors it served as a blanking signal that turned off the electron beam until it returned from the bottom of the screen to the top where it started to draw the next frame). A window starts to be drawn on the screen at some time later, after the vblank signal, depending on the distance to the top (the number of lines).